Quasar how I can change the height of q-select
I can't change the q-select in the quasar framework, I tried a long time also can't make it.
<q-select v-model="site1" outline dense class="selection" />

:deep(.selection .q-field__control) {font-size: 13px; width: 250px;}

:deep(.selection .q-field__outlined){ height: 28px;}

I want it the q-select of height will be 28px.

What do you see in your browser devtools? Is it targeting it? Is it overridden there?

actual height cannot be smaller than any min-height value, which some of the elements most likely have.  you can set your own min-height to override.  alternatively, have you tried dense prop on q-select?  it may give you the look you want without any CSS.  based on the internal makeup of q-select, you'll need to apply custom CSS to many different elements otherwise.

Yes, I have tried to use dense, but it also a bit height, I want lower a bit.



.k-mini-input .q-field__control,
.k-mini-input .q-field__inner,
.k-mini-input .q-field__marginal,
.k-mini-input .q-field__control input {
    height: 28px !important;
    min-height: 28px !important;
}

.k-mini-input .q-field__control,
.k-mini-input .q-field__native {
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.k-mini-input .q-field__inner {
    min-height: 28px;
}

.k-mini-input .q-field__native {
    min-height: 28px !important;
}



I have sometnig like this in my project. This example works with q-select and also for q-input. My version also requires k-mini-input class on q-select. You can probably replace that with q-select class if you want to change all selects in your application.

Finally, your solutions it can work!!!!!!! Thank you

I've had success in modifying some of the q-elements through the app.scss or app.css (whichever you use). Modifying them inline or via classes elsewhere does not seem to work.
